# Multiple boolean checks or an invalids counter

Tags: logic, design-patterns

What is your preferred way to implement actions based on the invalidity of multiple variables:

ie:

```
invalid_get() {
    return a_invalid || b_invalid || c_invalid;
}

a_invalid_set(v) {
    a_invalid=v;
    if(v) {
        validate_add();
    } else {
        validate_remove();
    }
}
function validate_remove() {
    if(!invalid_get()) {
        validate_remove_do();
    }
}
```

OR:

```
var invalids_num:Int;
function a_invalid_set(v) {
    a_invalid=v;
    if(v) {
        ++invalids_num;
        validate_add();
    } else {
        --invalids_num;
        validate_remove();
    }
}

validate_remove() {
    if(invalids_num==0) {
        validate_remove_do();
    }
}
```

I am guessing that a int check against 0 is faster and is without question the correct pattern, certainly for a large number of properties.

Comment: I would say that what methodology you use depends on the situation. Do you just want to say something is wrong, then even a simple boolean will suffice, if you want to say something is wrong and indicate the first attribute that is in error is another situation, and indicating each and every attribute that is in error is yet another. So it depends on the requirements

Comment: This would be a better fit for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This isn't actual code. This is a pattern that occurs widely where you need to stop validation when a property is returned to a state that is not longer invalid, and thus there occurs the possibility that validation is no longer necessary, but there needs to be a check whether there are other properties that are still invalid.